# Как правильно сортировать классы в проекте в Android Studio?

Tags: android

Я работаю над проектом в Android Studio и хочу правильно научиться сортировать классы в проекте. Я знаю о папках java, res и т.д., но мне нужны более подробные советы для классов именно в папке java. Существуют ли какие-то общепринятые правила или советы по сортировке файлов в проекте Android Studio?

Comment: Для начало исправьте на правильно "научиться".

Comment: Начните с пакетов: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html

Comment: гуглите android паттерны проектирования, смотрите как устроены проекты на том же гите, ну и все зависит от проекта, тут нет какого-то золотого правила